# save the values from dictionary in django fields running a for loop

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, dictionary

I am sending a dictionary with key as model fields in django and want to save them running a `for` loop like this:

```
for key in dictionary:
    object.key = dictionary[key]
    object.save()
```

Here, the keys are the exact names of model fields, but it is not getting saved.

For example, if one of the keys is `about`, it is trying to save the value in `object.key` instead of `object.about`.

What am I doing wrong? **How should I run the `for` loop so as to save the values in the object?**

Comment: Can you give an example of `dictionary`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting the values on your object properly. You can use `setattr`, to set the values in the dictionary to the corresponding object attribute

```
for key in dictionary:
    setattr(object, key, dictionary[key])
object.save()
```

`save` should be called after all the attributes have been set in the object

Comment: It worked fine and i will accept it. But it would be great if you could give a little explanation as to why the way i was doing it, it was not working and why setattr is working. It might be a big help.

Comment: An example. When `key='about'`, `settattr` takes the value from `dictionary['about']` and sets it to `object.about`. This action is repeated for all the keys in the dictionary. After the loop (not in the loop) `save` is called to avoid saving every time an attribute is set. The method you tried will attempt to set only `object.key` to all the values in the dictionary and only the last value gets picked.

Answer (score 4):

You can instantiate a Django model by passing its attributes to the constructor as kwargs, e.g.:

```
model = Model(attr1=value1, attr2=value2)
```

This means you can instantiate a model based on your dictionary like this:

```
model = Model(**dictionary)
```